# Declaring an object with templates and arguments at the same time

Tags: c++, templates

I don't know how to declare an object using templates and arguments at the same time

Basically, I have:

**FileLog.h**

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>

#include "FileOutput.h"
using namespace std;

template<class T, class R>
class FileLog : public FileOutput
{
    public:
        FileLog(const string file_name) : FileOutput(file_name)
          {
        };
...
```

And when I create an object :

** Main.cpp**

```
FileLog<int, int> object;
```

I get the error

no matching function for call to `'FileLog<int, int>::FileLog()'`

And i don't know how to give the string "Filename" in input to it

Comment: The same way you would do it if the class was not a template.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you'd instantiate a non template object :

```
FileLog<int, int> object("foo.txt");
```